# Что делать если программа не стартует?

Tags: c++

Доброго времени суток! Я написала программу, но она не запускается, даже нет никаких сообщений об ошибке. Можете помочь? Собственно, сама программа:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;
int keybard_enter(int matrix[3][7])  
{ fstream file1;
    file1.open("C:\\SOURCE\\Project\\matrix.txt", ios::out);
    int i, j;
    for (i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    { for (j = 0; j < 7; j++)
            { cin >> matrix[i][j];
              file1 << matrix[i][j] << " "; }
    }
    cout << endl;
    file1.close();
    return matrix[3][7];}


int file_enter(int matrix[3][7])
{ int i, j;
    fstream file1;
    file1.open("C:\\SOURCE\\Project\\matrix.txt", ios::in);
    cout << "Массив:" << endl;
    for (i = 0; i < 3; i++)
       { for (j = 0; j < 7; j++)
           { file1 >> matrix[i][j];
            cout << matrix[i][j] << "  "; }
         cout<<endl; }
    file1.close();
    return matrix[3][7];}


void out_matrix_file(int matrix[3][7])  
{ int i, j;
    fstream file1;
    file1.open("C:\\SOURCE\\Project\\end_matrix.txt", ios::out);
    file1 << "Конечная матрица:"; file1 << "\r";
    for (i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        { file1 << "\n";
          for (j = 0; j < 7; j++)
          { file1 << matrix[i][j] << "  "; }
        file1 << "\r";}
    file1.close();
    cout << "\nФайл успешно создан!\n\n";
}


void rewrite_matrix (int matrix[3][7])  
{char answer2;
cout << "1. Найти положительные числа 2. Найти отрицательные числа 3. Найти нулевые числа " << endl;
cin>>answer_2;
switch (answer2)
{case '1': int n=0;
for(int i=0;i< 3;i++){
for(int j=0;j< 6;j++){
if(matrix[i][j]>0) {n=n+1;}}}
fstream file1;
file1.open("C:\\SOURCE\\qwerty.dot", ios::out);
file1<<"Положительных чисел  "<<n;
file1.close(); break;

case '2': int m=0;
for(int i=0;i< 3;i++){
for(int j=0;j< 6;j++){
if(matrix[i][j]>0) m=m+1;}}}
fstream file1;
file1.open("C:\\SOURCE\\qwerty.dot", ios::out);
file1<<"Отрицательных  чисел  "<<m;
file1.close(); break;

case '3': int k=0;
for( int i=0;i< 3;i++){
for(int j=0;j< 6;j++){
if(matrix[i][j]>0) {k=k+1;}}}
fstream file1;
file1.open("C:\\SOURCE\\qwerty.dot", ios::out);
file1<<"Нулевых чисел  "<<k;
file1.close(); break;
default: cout << "Выберите 1, 2, 3!";break;
}


int main()  
{   int matrix[3][7];
    char answer1, answer2;
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "russian");
    cout << "\n Подсчёт элементов.\n" << endl;

    inception:
        cout << "\nПрограмма подсчёта.\n" << endl;
        cout << "1. Загрузить массив из файла.\n2. Ввести вручную.\n" << endl;

        cin>>answer1;

        switch (answer1)
               {
                 case '1': file_enter(matrix); break;
                 case '2': keybard_enter(matrix); break;
                 default: cout << "Выберите 1 или 2!"; goto inception; break;
               }
        cout << endl;

    for (;;)
    {
        cout << "\n1. Изменить элемент массива.\
                 \n2. Записать конечный массив в файл.\
                 \n3. Выйти из программы.\n" << endl;

        cin>>answer2;

        if (answer2 == '3') {break;}
        switch (answer2) {
            case '1': rewrite_matrix(matrix); break;
            case '2': out_matrix_file(matrix); break;
            default: cout << "\nВыберите 1, 2 или 4!\n"; break;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Кажется такой вопрос уже был, но его почему-то удалили) в коде встречается использование переменной `answer_2` но она нигде не объявлена. вот вам одна из ошибок компиляции. Не верится что компилятор совсем ничего не выдал.

Comment: Спасибо тебе добрый человек. Я тоже удивилась, что удалили. Пойду исправлю. Ещё раз спасибо!

Comment: Согласно правилам сообщества вопросы не должны сводится к завершению задач за учащихся. Приведите пример **вашей** реализации и описанием конкретных проблем.

Answer (score 1):

Вот лог, использовал тот же самый Code::Blocks (gcc-4.9.2)

`||=== Build: Debug in test (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler) ===|
D:\Development\Projects\C++\test\main.cpp||In function 'void rewrite_matrix(int (*)[7])':|
D:\Development\Projects\C++\test\main.cpp|65|error: jump to case label [-fpermissive]|
D:\Development\Projects\C++\test\main.cpp|60|error:   crosses initialization of 'std::fstream file1'|
D:\Development\Projects\C++\test\main.cpp|56|error:   crosses initialization of 'int n'|
D:\Development\Projects\C++\test\main.cpp|71|error: 'm' was not declared in this scope|
D:\Development\Projects\C++\test\main.cpp|72|error: break statement not within loop or switch|
D:\Development\Projects\C++\test\main.cpp|74|error: case label ''3'' not within a switch statement|
D:\Development\Projects\C++\test\main.cpp|78|error: redeclaration of 'std::fstream file1'|
D:\Development\Projects\C++\test\main.cpp|69|note: 'std::fstream file1' previously declared here|
D:\Development\Projects\C++\test\main.cpp|81|error: break statement not within loop or switch|
D:\Development\Projects\C++\test\main.cpp|82|error: case label not within a switch statement|
D:\Development\Projects\C++\test\main.cpp|82|error: break statement not within loop or switch|
||=== Build failed: 10 error(s), 0 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 1 second(s)) ===|`

Теперь по порядку:

1. В функции `void rewrite_matrix(int (*)[7])` ВСЕ объявления переменных вынести перед конструкцией `switch`.
2. Банальная ошибка: из-за плохо оформленного кода количество открывающих и закрывающих скобок не совпадает.

Немного привел код в порядок (исправил и привел в читабельный вид с помощью встроенного в Code::Blocks плагина Source code formatter (AStyle)):

```
void rewrite_matrix (int matrix[3][7]) {
    char answer2;
    int n=0;
    int m=0;
    int k=0;
    fstream file1;
    cout << "1. Найти положительные числа 2. Найти отрицательные числа 3. Найти нулевые числа " << endl;
    cin>>answer_2;
    switch (answer2) {
    case '1':
        for(int i=0; i< 3; i++) {
            for(int j=0; j< 6; j++) {
                if(matrix[i][j]>0) {
                    n=n+1;
                }
            }
        }
        file1.open("C:\\SOURCE\\qwerty.dot", ios::out);
        file1<<"Положительных чисел  "<<n;
        file1.close();
        break;

    case '2':
        for(int i=0; i< 3; i++) {
            for(int j=0; j< 6; j++) {
                if(matrix[i][j]>0)
                    m=m+1;
            }
        }
        file1.open("C:\\SOURCE\\qwerty.dot", ios::out);
        file1<<"Отрицательных  чисел  "<<m;
        file1.close();
        break;

    case '3':
        for( int i=0; i< 3; i++) {
            for(int j=0; j< 6; j++) {
                if(matrix[i][j]>0) {
                    k=k+1;
                }
            }
        }
        file1.open("C:\\SOURCE\\qwerty.dot", ios::out);
        file1<<"Нулевых чисел  "<<k;
        file1.close();
        break;
    default:
        cout << "Выберите 1, 2, 3!";
        break;
    }
}
```

Просто замените вашу функцию `void rewrite_matrix (int matrix[3][7])` на ту, что я привел, и в начале после `using namespace std;` добавьте `std::string answer_2;`.